# django - How to save info of the user which formits the form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to put in a form the sex of the UserProfile who's logged in.
This is the UserProfile's class:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    FEMALE = 'FEMALE'
    MALE = 'MALE'
    SEX = (
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
    )        
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=SEX, default=MALE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here is the view:

```
@login_required
def add_post(request):
    form = PostForm()
    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            return index(request)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    return render(request, 'rango/add_post.html', {'form': form})
```

PostForm:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    discord = forms.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="Please enter the title of the post.")
    post = forms.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="Please enter the post.")
    telegram = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter your telegram id.")
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ("user",)
```

Here is the Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    discord = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
    post = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
    telegram = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):  # For Python 2, use __unicode__ too
        return self.post
```

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: can you upload your `PostForm`?

Comment: @seuling sure, did it!

Comment: I don't understand.. your `PostForm` is for saving `Post` model object, right? Then why your `form.save` is profile?

Comment: @seuling Maybe you didn't understand because I hadn't put "user" in the exclude, in the PostForm. My bad.
I am also adding the Post model.

Comment: Then where's your `Post` model? can you upload it too?

Comment: @seuling done. Sorry.

Comment: ok I got it. I'm confusing becuase your `profile = form.save(commit=False)`. It should be `post = form.save(commit=False)'`, right? your `add_post` it's for create `Post` object. And what you want to do is also save `sex` when saving blog post, right?

Comment: @seuling, yes, the name "profile" isn't very good.
And yes, what I would like to do is to save sex when saving the blog post.

Comment: As a sidenote, you probably should ask for _gender_ instead of _sex_. There is a slight distinction between these terms, and for some people it is quite sensitive topic. Forcing picking one, while very convenient technically, will make some people uncomfortable. On the technical side, I guess you should just just explicitly inject this information from the view, when creating the form. You inject the user anyway, right?

Comment: @Frax yeah, english is not my first language, gender is a much better term, thanks for the idea. I was planning to add also something like "other" in the gender field, but now this is just a prototype, thanks for the tips though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add extra fields for `PostForm`.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # add extra fields for sex
    sex = forms.CharField(...)

    discord = forms.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="Please enter the title of the post.")
    post = forms.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="Please enter the post.")
    telegram = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter your telegram id.")
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ("user",)
```

Then save it inside view.

```
@login_required
def add_post(request):
    form = PostForm()
    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # it will be post
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            sex = form.cleaned_data.get('sex')
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()

            # this is real profile from UserProfile model
            profile = post.user.userprofile
            profile.sex = sex
            profile.save()
            return index(request)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    return render(request, 'rango/add_post.html', {'form': form})
```

p.s. I don't know clearly how your `UserProfile` and `User` related. I guess it's `OneToOneField`, then you can get profile by `post.user.userprofile`

I hope you solve it well!

Comment: I am getting the error "User has no userprofile." whenever I try to post something: in /views.py in add_post profile = post.user.userprofile What could I do?

Comment: how your `User` and `UserProfile` models related? OneToOne?

Comment: Yes, they weren't but I've put a 
"user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)" in the UserProfile model.

Comment: Ok. I thounght your userprofile and user model is related. If you add it, it will work.

Comment: I've put 
"user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)"
in the UserProfile model but I am still getting the error.
Am I missing something?

Comment: which message do you get??

Comment: I get "User has no userprofile" 

in /views.py in add_post profile = post.user.userprofile